# Sequence and Trigger PL/SQL script for Automatic ID generation on a table

Tags: plsql, triggers, sequence

Can someone help me fix that code. It doesn´t run on PL/SQL (SQLPLUS @script.sql), giving 
SP2-0552: Bind variable "NEW" not declared.

Script.SQL

```
  prompt Creating Table SYSTEMDATALOG;

declare 
    counter1 integer;
    counter2 integer;

begin
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter1 FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='SYSTEMDATALOG' AND OWNER='MZMESDB';

    if counter1 = 1 then 
        DROP TABLE SYSTEMDATALOG;
    end if;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter2 FROM ALL_SEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCE NAME='SEQSYSTEMDATALOG';

    if counter2 = 1 then 
        DROP SEQUENCE SEQSYSTEMDATALOGID;
    endif;

    CREATE TABLE "MZMESDB"."SYSTEMDATALOG" ( "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL , 
                         "DATETIME" DATE NOT NULL , 
                         "TYPE" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL, 
                         "SEVERITY" INTEGER NOT NULL,
                         "SOURCE" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL, 
                         "USER" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
                         "MESSAGE" VARCHAR2(1024), PRIMARY KEY ("ID") VALIDATE );


    CREATE SEQUENCE SEQSYSTEMDATALOGID;

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGSYSTEMDATALOGID
        BEFORE INSERT ON SYSTEMDATALOG
        FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                SELECT SEQSYSTEMDATALOGID.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
            END TRIGSYSTEMDATALOGID;
end;
/
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

[DEFINITIVE CODE]

prompt Creating Table SYSTEMDATALOG;

declare
    counter1 integer;
    counter2 integer;

begin
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter1 FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='SYSTEMDATALOG' AND OWNER='MZMESDB';

```
if counter1 = 1 then 
    execute immediate 'DROP TABLE SYSTEMDATALOG';
end if;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter2 FROM ALL_SEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME='SEQSYSTEMDATALOG';

IF counter2 = 1 then
    execute immediate 'DROP SEQUENCE SEQSYSTEMDATALOGID';
END IF;

execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE "MZMESDB"."SYSTEMDATALOG" ( 
                    "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL , 
                    "DATETIME" DATE NOT NULL , 
                    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL, 
                    "SEVERITY" INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    "SOURCE" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL, 
                    "USER" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
                    "MESSAGE" VARCHAR2(1024), PRIMARY KEY ("ID") VALIDATE )';

execute immediate 'CREATE SEQUENCE SEQSYSTEMDATALOGID';

execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGSYSTEMDATALOGID
           BEFORE INSERT ON SYSTEMDATALOG
           FOR EACH ROW
           BEGIN
            SELECT SEQSYSTEMDATALOGID.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
           END TRIGSYSTEMDATALOGID;';
```

end;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you are mixing PL/SQL (an anonymous PL/SQL block) and DDL. While you can write DML statements (SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) in PL/SQL you cannot write DDL (CREATE/DROP etc) directly in PL/SQL.

You need to either run your DDL statements outside the anonymous PL/SQL block or use
`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '<statement>';`.

As for the error on `:NEW` I think it will disappear when you fix the other issue. If it doesn't, try adding:

`SET SCAN OFF`

In the beginning of your SQL*PlUS file.

Comment: I was using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with no success as well. I changed the script because it was not working...

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your execute immediate code:

1. An `end if;` is misspelt as `endif;`

2. Some string constants aren't surronded by apostrophes (`SYSTEMDATALOG ` should be `'SYSTEMDATALOG'`).

Comment: Endif was indeed an error. I have tried with and without quotes and the behaviour is the same. Even fixing the endif I still get "Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: if" at the last line at the PL/SQL processor.

Comment: I tried it (although I exchanged all DDL with `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`) and when I fixed the `endif` the error message disappeared.

Comment: I´ve changed the post title and added the final working code. Some hours lost on that, but this can be usefull for someone else. Thanks for helpping.